# Math Analysis - Two Bounded Functions and partitions proof

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f,g:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb R$ be bounded functions and $g$ is increasing. Show that for every partitions $P$ and $Q$ of $[a,b]$ with $P\le Q$ we have $s(f,P,g) \le s(f,Q,g) \le S(f,Q,g)\le S(f,P,g).$

I'm having trouble getting started with the proof and looking to be pointed in the right direction. I'm not sure how $g$ being a non-decreasing function helps me.

Comment: You have to explain your notation.  Does $P \leq Q$ mean it's a subpartition?  What is $s$ and $S$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can only guess, that it's about the *Riemann-Stieltjes integral* $\int_a^b f\,dg$, a generalization of the usual Riemann integral (applying it with $g(x)=x$), and that 
$$s(f,P,g)=\sum_i\left(\min_{[a_i,a_{i+1}]}f\right)\cdot(g(a_{i+1})-g(a_i)) $$
where $[a_i,a_{i+1}]$ constitute the partition $P$, and $S$ is the same with $\max$. I also assume that $P\le Q$ means that the dividing points of $P$ are also dividing points of $Q$, i.e. $Q$ is finer.

The middle inequality is obvious. For the other ones, first show them for the coarsest $P$, i.e. which has only one interval, (the whole $[a,b]$), and $Q$ is arbitrary. Then, for a general $P$, apply it to all intervals of $P$.